# Fetch Parent & Child Data Using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, mysqli, relationship

I am using Laravel 5.7 and I want to show `child` data using `parent id.`

I created a `CategoryController`  and I am fetching the data by `parent id` shown here. However, I want to show all the data in the `index` page.

```php
<?php

$parentCat = Category::where('parent', 0)->get();
foreach ($parentCat as $parent) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $parent->category_name;
    $category = Category::where('parent', $parent->id)->get();

    foreach ($category as $child) {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $child->category_name;
    }

}

return view('fnf.category.index')->with('parent', $parentCat);
```

[image]

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Man</th>
        <th><a href=""> Edit</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shirt</td>
        <td><a href=""> Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shirt</td>
        <td><a href=""> Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Woman</th>
        <th><a href=""> Edit</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Woman Shirt</td>
        <td><a href=""> Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what your question is here? It seams your current code shows correctly the parent and child structures?

Comment: i want to show all child category by parent id

Comment: like `$parent_id = 1; $sql = "select * from category where paremt='$parent_id'"`

Comment: "like parent_id = 1;" I believe it's just as simple as `Category::where('parent',1)->get();` instead off `Category::where('parent',0)->get();`

Comment: how can i send `return view('fnf.category.index')->with('parent',$parentCat);` with child and parent

Comment: see my code up . i already write . how can use `foreach ` and get parent category and child category at a time

Comment: i believe just as simple as adding `$parentCat->category =  $category` somewhere after `$category  = Category::where('parent',$parent->id)->get();` or after the foreach loop `foreach ($category as $child){..}`  Normally native PHP code would allow objects to be build this way not sure if it will cause errors in Laravel..

Comment: it's easy to show on `controller`  but result show only  `index.blade.php` page